# In Emacs, a combination of visual-line-mode and toggle-truncate-lines makes C-e not go to the end of the line. How do I fix that

Tags: emacs, elisp

With `visual-line-mode` enabled in Emacs, long lines wrap at natural breaks in the text, allowing me to see all of the text on any given line. `Wrap` appears in my status bar. Sometimes I want to the lines to not wrap. I can toggle that state by command: `M-x visual-line-mode`. However, when I do that, `C-e` does not take me to the end of the line, but instead somewhere towards a "screenwidth" or so, though it seems to be variable.

I can fix that problem by calling `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` after running the `M-x visual-line-mode`, but what I'd like to do is use a single Function key command to run both commands in sequence.

In my `.emacs` file I currently have this:

```
(global-set-key [f8] 'toggle-truncate-lines)
(global-set-key [f9] 'visual-line-mode)
```

With these keys defined, I can use the function keys `f9` and `f8` in sequence to get the results I want. I thought I could write an elisp function to call the two functions in sequence, and then map a single function key to that function, like so:

```
(defun unwrap-lines ()
  "Unwrap lines, and fix the C-e not to the end problem"
  (interactive)
  (visual-line-mode)
  (toggle-truncate-lines))

(global-set-key [f10] 'unwrap-lines)
```

However, after defining this function, it seems to only call the second command in my function `toggle-truncate-lines`, and skips the `visual-line-mode` aspect of the function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Visual line mode is turned off with `(visual-line-mode -1)`   You might also want to make sure that you are not using `global-visual-line-mode` which affects everything.

Comment: Thatnks! That was the part I was missing.